# Regex searching for a letter starting a word and next word containing another word

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

How might I search through a list of names and only return the names that have a word starting with 's' and the next word starting with 'mary'?

For example, I have 2 titles: "Avera St. Mary's Hospital" and "Arthritis Care Specialists of Maryland". I search 'S Mary' and would like it to return "Avera St. Mary's Hospital" not "Arthritis Care Specialists of Maryland". My code returns both...Any help would be much appreciated!

```
var testList = new List<string>();
List<string> titles = new List<string>();
titles.Add("Avera St. Mary's Hospital");
titles.Add("Arthritis Care Specialists of Maryland");
foreach (var title in titles)
{
    var pattern = @"(?<!\w)s.*\smary";
    Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match m = r.Match(title);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        testList.Add(title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.*` is the problem within the regular expression given in the question. That `.*` matches too much text. (Changing it to a non-greedy `.*?` will not work.)

From the question and additional example in comments, the match should be of:

- A word starting with `s`. The definition of "word" is not precise but using "any characters that are not spaces" matches the examples.
- A separator between two words. Assume that one or more spaces is allowed.
- A word starting with the letters `mary`. Anything may follow these four characters.

This leads to the simple regular expression: `\bs[^ ]* +mary`

```
\b               A word boundary
s                This exact character
[^ ]*            Zero or more characters that are not spaces
 +               One or more spaces
mary             These exact characters
```

---

Combining and sorting the examples in the question and the comments gives these as example that should match:

```
Avera St. Mary's Hospital
Carondelet St. Mary's Hospital.
Centre Hospitalier St- Mary,
saint mary,
Saint Mary's Home of Erie,
st mary
st mary's
st. mary,
```

These are example that should not match:

```
Arthritis Care Specialists of Maryland
Cardiovascular Specialists Of Central Maryland,
```

Comment: Would it be possible to skip a word? For example if I had an entry named "Albuquerque Associated Podiatrists" and I searched 'alb podia' then it would return that entry. Right now the regex pattern will only return "Albuquerque Associated Podiatrists" if I search 'alb associa' (after the space has to be the next word. What if it's a word in the name but not necessarily the next one). I just replaced the 's' and the 'mary' exact charaters in the regex pattern for this example.

Comment: Are you now wanting to match strings like `Specialists of Maryland` that were excluded in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your regular expression like:

`var pattern = @"(?<!\w)s\w+[-|`|~|@|(|)|.]*[\s]+Mary";`

**[-|`|~|@|(|)|.]** specifies the special characters allowed between **S*** and Mary like **St- Mary**

Comment: It seems to me it would return the two values. I think @Seth Pacheco should instead change the the expression to be *word boundary* or *word end* after `mary`. I don't know the specific escape sequence for it in C#, but he can search.

Comment: I am not sure about other conditions but I tested these two inputs in my console application and got just one in the output.

Comment: OP needs to clarify what is the criteria for accepting/rejecting an entry into the list.

Comment: This answer does work with the example. The criteria for the search is to return anything that has "st mary," "st. mary," "saint mary," or possibly the plural of mary ("mary's"). So if there was a couple more strings in the list, "Cardiovascular Specialists Of Central Maryland," "Centre Hospitalier St- Mary," "Saint Mary's Home of Erie," and "Carondelet St. Mary's Hospital." I would want the search to the last three not the first ("Cardiovascular Specialists Of Central Maryland"). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Put a `\b` — which means **word boundary** after `mary`.

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRGhSQ01YRzBwODg)